# MFMailComposer - embed a clickable link in message body?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Im trying to format a message body for the MailComposer and I want come clickable links in it.
I know that you can use :setMessageBody isHTML; but my proublem is the when i put in something like

```
someString@"<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/path/to/link\">Click Me!</a>\n"
```

I get errors in XCode because the html quoataion marks are being seen as the end of string quotation marks.

Can anyone please tell me how to work around this. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you get compilation errors, because you've escaped your quotation marks (`\"`).

Comment: fair point. I'm just being an idiot. Thx

Comment: Caused by typo: missing assignment operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me both the case works

```
NSString * someString = nil;
someString = @"<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/path/to/link\">Click Me!</a>\n";
someString = @"<a href='http://www.mysite.com/path/to/link'>Click Me!</a>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setSubject:@"Your Subject"];

        NSString *strHtmlBody = @"<html><body><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">DISPLAY TEXT</a></body></html>";

        [controller setMessageBody:strHtmlBody isHTML:YES];

        if (controller)
            [viewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];

    }
```